# Expresso Store - White Screen @ checkout

Tags: expresso-store, white-screen-of-death

I updated to EE 2.5.5 & Store 1.6.2 and ever since the `{exp:store:checkout} {/exp:store:checkout}` tag pair returns the white screen when any action is completed (update / empty / remove / next)

I quickly uploaded the store_example templates to test and the same issue was there.

So I backed up the Database, and then ran an uninstall / reinstall on the Store module - the functionality returns but I obviously lose all of the data - order information / products / etc and there are thousands.

I replaced `exp_store_config.store_preferences` with the hash from the reinstalled Store but this didn't help - my guess is that it's a bodged upgrade... I'll try manually changing the version numbers to force an update...

Currently the store is offline as it's impossible to make any purchases so any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

As the post data doesn't submit, it's available in the Output Profiler. [image: exp_store checkout action]

thanks,

J

Comment: OK - Seems it was a knackered update. I edited exp_modules.module_version in the Database to 1.5.0 and then re-ran the upgrade. All working fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was a botched upgrade, so I had to run the upgrade over.

To do this, I manually edited the `exp_modules.module_version` table for store to `1.5.0` then hit run module updates in addons -> modules.

All works as expected now.